# Getting different results with mysql when using python multiprocessing

Tags: python, mysql, multiprocessing

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong(or how to correct it).  It might be easier to show some code(its a bit simplified from what I'm doing but it proves my point):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import MySQLdb
import sys

#sql connection
try:
    conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "127.0.0.1",user = "user",passwd = "password", db = "mydb")
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
     print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
     sys.exit (1)

#with database
cursor = conn.cursor ()
cursor.execute ("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data_table")
cursor.execute ("""
    CREATE TABLE data_table(
        value     CHAR(80)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM 
""")

cursor.execute (""" INSERT INTO data_table (value) VALUES ('%s')""" % [0, 0]) #need to insert basecase
conn.commit()


def build_table(i,x):    # i is index, x is data[i]
    conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "127.0.0.1",user = "user",passwd = "password", db = "mydb")
    cursor = conn.cursor ()
    #print i,x
    target_sum = 100
    for s in range(target_sum + 1): 
        for c in range(target_sum + 1): 
            #print c, i
            cursor.execute ("""
INSERT INTO data_table (value) 
   SELECT  '%s'
   FROM dual
   WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data_table WHERE value='%s' )
         = 1
     AND NOT EXISTS
         ( SELECT * FROM data_table WHERE value='%s' )
           """ % ([s, i+1], [s - c * x, i], [s, i+1]))
            conn.commit()

    conn.close()

data = [2,5,8]
pool = Pool(processes=4)
for i, x in enumerate(data): 
    build_table(i,x) #creates 250 records
    #pool.apply_async(build_table, (i, x))
pool.close()
pool.join()

print 'completed'
```

It basically creates a table in mysql. The code above creates 250 entries(which is correct), but if you comment out `build_table(i,x)` in the for loop and uncomment `pool.apply_async(build_table, (i, x))` it creates only 52 records.  Why is there a difference when multiprocessing the same function and is there anything I can do to fix it so the results are the same(I thought quickly committing updates would fix it but no luck)?

If I play around `pool = Pool(processes=4)` and change it to 1, it works but I guess thats expected because its not multiprocessing really at that point. Also, if it helps I'm using InnoDB.

UPDATE: when I change to MyISAM I get 240 results being updated(not quite the 250 I need but much better than 52).

UPDATE2: mysql command was combined into a single command, and results seem to vary. Sometimes I get 248 results in the database, sometimes 240 or less. Maybe multiprocessing is causing this diverge between expected and actual results ?

Comment: I can't untie all the complex logic and what values you are actually trying to Insert, but I guess that the interleaving threads/processes cause some values to be inserted twice or not at all and thus affecting the 2nd and 3rd steps of other processes. Between one's process 1st Select and 2nd Select, another process can Insert that value (that first process thinks is missing). A similar thing can happen between the 2nd Select and the Insert.

Comment: @ypercube sorry for the complex logic..I spent over 10 hours with this problem then the last hour trying to create a simplified example and double nested for statement was the only way I could recreate it. I thought what you were saying was happening but I thought quickly committing the changes would fix it.

Comment: Is the table InnoDB or MyISAM? In which serialization level are you runing?

Comment: Another thing. I guess your real problem (not the simplified one) will be to insert much more values into the table (and possibly with more than one column). Can you provide details on that problem? Perhaps it can be solved by only a few Inserts, without the need to complexity.

Comment: Is it not feasible to store the results of the `pool` computation in a temporary array, and then write them to the database?

Comment: @ypercube I'm going to read up on the differences but I'm using InnoDB on mysql.  I'm basically creating a table and searching for a value in the database, if it exists then create the next value.
-senderle I'm not sure what you mean. Jobs are referencing each others state(I used to use a shared dict for this job before but now using mysql) I try to, as quickly as possible, commit the result so its avail.

Comment: What I would try is to combine the 2 Selects and the Insert in one Insert statement.

Comment: @ypercube you are a genius! The problem is not fully solved yet, but switching to MyISAM seems to have increase the results from 52 to 240(I need 250) but this did help.  How can I combine the selects/insert into one statement?

Comment: I would keep InnoDB. Try disabling auto_commit (not sure how to do that through the Python cursor). If that doesn't work, set the serialization level to `SERIALIZABLE`: [Transactions and serialzations levels](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to combine the 2 Selects and the Insert in one Insert statement:

```
#print c, i
cursor.execute(""" SELECT value FROM data_table WHERE value='%s' """ % ([s - c * x, i]))
if cursor.rowcount == 1:
    cursor.execute(""" SELECT value FROM data_table WHERE value='%s' """ % [s, i+1])
    if cursor.rowcount == 0:
        cursor.execute (""" INSERT INTO data_table (value) VALUES ('%s')""" % [s, i+1])
```

Into something like:

```
#print c, i
cursor.execute ("""
    INSERT INTO data_table (value) 
       SELECT  '%s'
       FROM dual
       WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data_table WHERE value='%s' )
             = 1
         AND NOT EXISTS
             ( SELECT * FROM data_table WHERE value='%s' )
               """ % ([s, i+1], [s - c * x, i], [s, i+1]))
```

Not sure about the syntax in the last line. You'll need to pass 3 parameters.

Comment: The `NOT EXISTS ...` part can be removed if you add a `UNIQUE` constraint on column `value`.

Comment: Thanks. The code doesn't work but I do understand your logic, instead of multiple small commands just use one super sql statement one that combines all the criteria. Let me figure out how to do it and also i'll look into the suggestions you had in the comments about disabling auto commits.

Comment: update..when I set it back to InnoDB and run your code, I get 167 matches. I need to figure out how to get disable autocommit and maybe that makes it better. I'll update you, but def. making cool progress. So weird, I reran the code and now got 248 matches..and when I run it and then browse the net, it creates 240..hmm results seem to be different based on cpu usage.

Comment: The `WHERE (COUNT(*)) = 1` is very strange. Do you really need that? What is the logic behind that check (the first SELECT in your code)?

Comment: that was just an example, but basically the logic is just checking if a calculated value exists in the database. If it does then add a future value(if value does not already exist). My orginal code had a dictionary that searched for values in the dictionary, if the value didn't exist it created it as false, and if it found it again then it would turn it into true. So if [s - c * x, i] exists, then turn [s, i+1] into True. If it does not exist than turn it into False(but using that logic if its found again it turn into true). In python this is from 'defaultdict' command. I tried to recreate it

Comment: I do not want to over complicate it, but here's the presdo code of what I'm doing(the last part, the dict is what I'm trying to convert to mysql now instead of local memory): 
'for i = 1 to k
    for z = 0 to sum:
        for c = 1 to z / x_i:
            if T[z - c * x_i][i - 1] is true:
                set T[z][i] to true'
sorry i can't seem to format the code

Comment: okay I sort of figured a way around this.  Not the best solution but because I cannot have missing data, I rerun the thread and it gets everything.  My question is, when I re-run it would it make more sense to use my original simple sql statements as opposed to your more complex one? The reason is, 99% of the results are in the database already, I would just be going over those results and adding any missing results so would your sql command be okay or should i aim for something more simple(and maybe able to process quicker on the second loop).

Comment: I don't think it matters. Can you send me a link with the actual code so I can test? I guess the `data = [2, 5, 8]` is simplified, too.

Comment: If you have python then the latest code is in my question...I'll test a bit more and get back to you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7939/discussion-between-ypercube-and-lostsoul)

Comment: I had to sleep sorry, I'm awake now.  I ended up reverting back to my old code, although your code made things faster..I seem to be getting slightly better performance if I do the sperate reads then single inserts with the one column indexed.